# Highlighting any Duplicates in a DataGridView VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, vb.net-2010

I have a DataGridView which is populated from a MySQL DB, and on the click of a button I wish to validate the table by highlighting the duplicates in a specific column.

What is the best way to do this. The field isn't a primary key in the Database and is fine to be replicated, however it just needs to be made apparent that this is the case?

Comment: How many columns do you have? Can you indicate the Column Names?

Comment: Can you include a mockup with desired behavior in your question?

Answer (score 1):

This would be one way of doing it as suggested by #Cyborgx37

```
    Sub HighlightDupes(ByRef dgv As DataGridView, ByVal col_id As Integer)

    Dim dgvCol As DataGridViewColumn = dgv.Columns(col_id)
    dgv.Sort(dgvCol, System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)

    Dim numRows As Integer = dgv.Rows.Count() ''// or dgv.SelectedRows.Count() for the selected rows
    Dim flagFirstRow As Boolean = True
    Dim tempStr As String = ""

    For Each RW As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows ''// or dgv.SelectedRows for the selected rows
        On Error Resume Next
        If Not (flagFirstRow) Then
            If (RW.Cells(col_id).Value.ToString() = tempStr) Then

                ''// RW.Cells(col_id).Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
                ''// RW.Cells(col_id).Style.BackColor = Color.White

                RW.Cells(col_id).Selected = True
                dgv.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
                dgv.CurrentCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.White

                MsgBox("Dupe found: " & tempStr)

            End If

        End If
        tempStr = RW.Cells(col_id).Value.ToString()
        flagFirstRow = False
    Next

End Sub
```

.

You would call the sub using the datagridview name then the column index.
e.g. `HighlightDupes(DataGridView1, 0)` this would sort the first column, and find the dupes.

Not sure if the cell formatting will work correctly due to the sort. Might be better for filling an array then sorting that then find the dupes of that then loop through the dgv and set the formatting of the cell when it hasn't been sorted. Or you could have a look into the [dgv rowprepaint event](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?465358-RESOLVED-Change-DataGridView-cell-color-based-on-other-columns#post_message_3971087) might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Sort your DataGridView by the column you wish to highlight, then loop through each row. If the column value is the same as the previous value, apply a highlight.

If you want to get fancy, you could write a LINQ query against your data source (probably a DataTable, but could be something else) which groups by the desired column, counts the number of instances in each group, then select only those values with a count greater than 1. You could then use that as a lookup or join it back to the datasource to "mark" those rows which have a duplicate value. Applying the highlight would require checking this new field and then applying the highlight accordingly.

Don't have time to whip up some example code, but it shouldn't be too hard.

**EDIT**

1. Apply a sort with [DataGridView.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0868ft3z.aspx).
2. Iterate over the [Rows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows.aspx) collection.

   1. If the current row is the first row ([`Index`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewband.index.aspx)`= 0`) then skip
   2. Otherwise, get the value of the desired column from [Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.cells.aspx)[[columnName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ee9kshd.aspx)].[Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value.aspx) for the current row and previous row.
   3. Compare them. If they are the same, [apply a style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yef90x0.aspx), such as a background color.

Comment: Downvoter: It may not be the most helpful answer in the world, but would you really classify it as not useful? The OP simply asks for the best way, not code samples.